# Multiprocessing some_process.start() does not execute the function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In the code snippet below, .start() does not execute the method. The first print statement in self.listen_items() is never printed. There is a main file that instantiates a class to schedule and manage the instantiation of other classes as needed. The code here is from one of those classes. I have searched all morning for a hint as to the problem. Haven't found anything relating to the circumstances in my situation. Any ideas?

```
self.get_items_process = Process(target=self.listen_items, daemon=True, args=()) 
self.get_items_process.start()

def listen_items(self):
    """Method replaces listen_to_scheduler_utility() so we can manage exiting the thread on a test restart."""
    print("@@@ listen_items(start) @@@")
    while not self._restart_pending:
        print("@@@ listen_items(loop) @@@")
        item: QueueItem = self._scheduler_utility.get_item_from_queues(STR_ITERATION_CONTROLLER, self._iteration)
        if item is not None:
            print("@@@ listen_items(item) @@@")
            self.process_input(queue_item=item)
```

"""

Comment: Which OS? Do you run the code from command line or an IDE? The shown code is incomplete. Are you sure that "start" is executed?

Comment: The code as shown cannot be run (there cannot be any ``self`` that has the shown ``listen_items`` at this point). Are you sure the code executing the subprocesses is actually run?

Comment: The complete code cannot be shown for a number of reasons the most significant of which is security. The self.get_items_process = ... and the next line are both in the __init__() method of the class. If I use threading instead of process, it all works fine; however, there are significant reasons for moving to multiprocessing.

Comment: We have start.py with __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The main function instantiates schedule.py which in turn instantiates foobar.py which is where the code that I included is sourced.

Comment: The OS is Linux: Ubuntu

Comment: We are not asking for your complete code, we are asking for a *minimal* reproducible example. That may be an excerpt of your existing code, or new code that has the same problem. Based on your description, a class with ``__init__`` starting a process and a single method that calls ``print``, plus the code to instantiate this class are sufficient. See the [ask] page for details.

Comment: I have a test script that emulates this very setup and it works fine so I cannot reproduce it except in the environment from which it is failing so I guess I am screwed. The test script even works fine on the in the environment where the where the code that is failing is running. Thanks for the answers...

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I have found out. First, the start() method was working all along. A shell script starts the application process and I usually redirect stdout and stderr to a file. The print statements were not showing up in that file; however, if I did not redirect output, behold, they were spewed out to the terminal screen. I am a little fuzzy on why they don't show up in the redirect but I now understand what is happening. Multiprocessing on a Linux box does a fork main thread of execution so forked process was writing the messages but the parent process was the only one writing to the log file. Thanks for all the comments...